# Multiple web application deployment targets in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I currently maintain several different environments for a single application - production, staging, development, etc .

I was wondering if there was a setting or an add-in for visual studio that would facilitate publishing to multiple deployment targets (preferabbly with a different web.config for each target)?

I'm considering writing a couple of nant scripts instead but it would be nice if there was an integrated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in VS 2008 out of the box. I don't know if there's an addin for this, but you could try searching [VisualStudio Gallery](http://www.visualstudiogallery.com).

From what I've seen from demo videos, VS2010 will support having different web.configs, and deploying to dev/staging/production.